# How to configure PhpStorm to open external documentation, namely devdocs.io

Tags: phpstorm

I am looking for a plugin/settings **to open** http://devdocs.io (devdocs.io/#q=keyword) with **currently selected text**. Something similar to googleit plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7402?pr=phpStorm, but with configurable url...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with [External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) functionality.

The idea is to launch your app/script that will open such URL in a web browser.

How it can be done depends on your OS and tools you have got there. This is how it can be implemented **on Windows OS** (*URL will be opened in your default web browser*):

[image]

After you have create such external tool entry and it's working you can optionally assign custom shortcut. This can be done at `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- look for that entry under `External Tools` branch:

[image]

---

**NOTE:** 
Please note that if selection contains spaces then such search will partially fail as spaces will not be encoded into web safe `+` character (or `%20`) -- for such cases you will have to write shell/batch script that would perform such conversion and only then open such final URL.

Comment: Great, thank you! I will accept your answer as it contains other interesting notes + keyboard shortcut creation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [External Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/external-tools.html) for this:

```
File > Settings > Tools > External Tools > + (Add)
```

Enter a name like `DevDocs`. Depending on your OS and the web browser you are using, enter a command to open a website in `Program`. Use `$SelectedText$` as a placeholder for the selected text in IntelliJ IDEA. So for example, looking up the selected text under Windows/Chrome, the command may look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://devdocs.io/#q=$SelectedText$"
```

Now you can run the search from different places (which are listed under `Show in` in the same dialog) - e.g. MainMenu: `Tools > External Tools > YourToolName`.