# How to configure PhpStorm to show API namespaces documentation panel as in phpDesigner8

Tags: ide, phpstorm, phpdesigner

I would like to change from phpDesigner8 to JetBrains PhpStorm IDE.

But I would really miss phpDesigner8's sidepanel with its fast and easy access to different API namespace documentations (for PHP, CSS, HTML, JavaScript, even WordPress and so on) with drag and drop use of code.

See this screenshot:
[image: phpdesigners namespace panel]

How should I configure PhpStorm 2016 to get similar sidepanel view?

Note: actually I open one of external library files, then look at its structure view in the sidepanel which is somehow close, but far from a optimized workflow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Katie: thank you for superfast text edit,  well done!

Comment: There is no such built-in panel. Maybe some plugins (`Settings/Preferences | Plugins | Browse Repositories...`) .. but I have never looked for one like that myself. *I guess* this ticket is asking about something similar: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6491

Comment: @LazyOne: Thank you for the link.

Comment: I still try to find out how to get easy API Documention Overviews directly in a sidepanel. I  found that the Dash plugin: "Dash(Win=Velocity,Linux=Zeal) is an API Documentation Browser and Code Snippet Manager." opens external Velocity. But no well, easy, fast and directly in the sidepanel integrated solution. Perfect easy solution would be to have something like http://devdocs.io/ directly in a sidepanel view and directly pointing to API reference of code under the cursor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280460/how-to-configure-phpstorm-to-open-external-documentation-namely-devdocs-io